# How to remove recuring back slash from string

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I have this string that is coming out from a php string, how do i remove this charactor '\' from it.

```
'ewuououowe',\'post\',\'page\',\'attachment\',\'portfolio'
```

i have tried

```
 str_replace("\", "",  $string);
```

But it breaks because of that charactor

Comment: `str_replace("\\'", "",  $string);`

Comment: perfect, thank you so much  Avinash Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an `\` char to an string, you have to escape it, with the `\` - so you have just write it twice: `\\`

This would result in the following replace code

```
str_replace("\\'", "'",  $string);
```